# Merge Advanced View Positioning and View Animation functions

Tags: openlayers, javascript

I'm trying to merge two functions that are displayed as OL's samples, the [Advanced View Positioning](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/center.html) and the [View Animation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html). I can successfully change the view with the animation method, but I can't fix the zoom as in the Advanced View Postitioning method. I'm using these methods to change the view of some rasters loaded in OL. My problem is related only with the zoom level, how can I make it fit to the raster that I'm using? I believe that I need to get the raster extent (already did it) and somehow calculate and link to the zoom section in the `flyTo()` function.

OL version: 5.3

Function I'm using for the animation:

```
//This is one of the locations I using with the View Animation method
var randomLocation = transform(getCenter([565280.904542, 6924581.621580, 565319.267400, 6924554.342636]), 'EPSG:31982', 'EPSG:3857');

function flyTo(location, done) {
  var duration = 3000;
  var zoom = view.getZoom();
  var parts = 2;
  var called = false;
  function callback(complete) {
    --parts;
    if (called) {
      return;
    }
    if (parts === 0 || !complete) {
      called = true;
      done(complete);
    }
  }
  view.animate({
    center: location,
    duration: duration
  }, callback);
  view.animate({
    zoom: zoom - 2,
    duration: duration / 2
  }, {
    zoom: zoom,
    duration: duration / 2
  }, callback);
}
```

Some links that are related but did not help me (most of them use the `fit(extent)` function. I tried to use it but it cancels the `animate()` function):

- [Open Layers 4 fit to extent zoom too much out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246825/open-layers-4-fit-to-extent-zoom-too-much-out)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746970/openlayers-4-fit-to-extent-of-selected-features
- [OpenLayers-3 setting zoom so layers fit in map window](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150634/openlayers-3-setting-zoom-so-layers-fit-in-map-window)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369647/openlayers-animate-getview-fit
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361669/openlayers-map-jitters-on-dynamic-centering-of-feature-movement-animation
- [OpenLayers - Setting View Correctly Extent GEOJSon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255887/openlayers-setting-view-correctly-extent-geojson)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763661/openlayers-fit-extent-with-bounce
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190146/view-fit-using-view-animate-in-openlayers-3-20
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291471/openlayers-3-zoom-map-to-coordinates-in-array
- [View Animation of OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232110/view-animation-of-openlayers)

Comment: Instead of flying to `location` you should fly to where the full map will be centered if location is centered in the padded area.  An offset of `n` pixels on the screen is `n * view.getResolution()` in map coordinates.  You will need `map.getSize()` and the padding array to calculate the horizontal and vertical values for n.

Comment: Although it might be overkill in this case, for more complex animations such as rotation in an offset view you might need to offset the center of the map by using an oversized map and hiding the overflow.  Then as a quick way to reposition all the controls overlay the main map with a shared view map (as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/side-by-side.html except not side by side). http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/view-on-view-br.html http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/view-on-view-bl.html http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/view-on-view-tl.html http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/view-on-view-tr.html

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, the location that I'm using and trying to fly to is going to be centered on map, just as in the View Animation. I added a location that I'm using on top of the code to be more clear. In the Advanced View Positioning the algorithm get the geometry from the GeoJSON VectorSource to use the `view.fit()` function. I wonder if it is not possible to do the same with a raster and apply in this `flyTo()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I've experimented with the example and found an easy way to do it.  Use `.fit` to get the desired final outcome, save the resulting center and zoom, then immediately go back to the starting point.  You can then flight animate the same movement.  Any of the other animation examples should also work.

```
  var flytolausanne = document.getElementById('flytolausanne');
  flytolausanne.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var feature = source.getFeatures()[1];
    var point = /** @type {ol.geom.SimpleGeometry} */ (feature.getGeometry());
    var oldCenter = view.getCenter();
    var oldZoom = view.getZoom();
    view.fit(point, {padding: [170, 50, 30, 150], minResolution: 50});
    var newCenter = view.getCenter();
    var newZoom = view.getZoom();
    view.setCenter(oldCenter);
    view.setZoom(oldZoom);

    flightZoom = Math.min(oldZoom, newZoom) - 2;
    zoomUp = oldZoom - flightZoom;
    zoomDown = newZoom - flightZoom;

    var duration = 2000;
    var parts = 2;
    var called = false;
    function callback(complete) {
      --parts;
      if (called) {
        return;
      }
      if (parts === 0 || !complete) {
        called = true;
        //done(complete);
      }
    }
    view.animate({
      center: newCenter,
      duration: duration
    }, callback);
    view.animate({
      zoom: flightZoom,
      duration: duration * zoomUp / (zoomUp + zoomDown)
    }, {
      zoom: newZoom,
      duration: duration * zoomDown / (zoomUp + zoomDown)
    }, callback);

  }, false);
```

[image]

[image]

Just as someone has entered the coordinates for the outline of Switzerland in `switzerland.geojson` in the example you will need to define your own extent.  It you want to use same the extent as above you would simply replace the minimum resolution `fit` with constrain resolution for a best fit:

```
var extent = ol.proj.transformExtent([565280.904542, 6924581.621580, 565319.267400, 6924554.342636], 'EPSG:31982', 'EPSG:3857');
view.fit(extent, {padding: [170, 50, 30, 150], constrainResolution: false});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I already tried something like this. The problem is that I can't get the features with the `source.getFeatures()[1];` or the geometry from the raster. This is my only problem with the `view.fit()` function, since I can't use with the raster extention or other raster related object. I tried several ways to accomplish this, but all unsuccessful. Thats why I passed the raster extent in top of the code, being that I can get the extent from the ImageLayer without problems. This works nice if I have only vectors though.

Comment: To convert coordinates to a geometry `point = new.ol.geom.Point(randomLocation);`
The extent of a single coordinate is `randomLocation.concat(randomLocation);`

Comment: Okay, so using the `point = new Point({randomLocation});` gave me a blank screen with no erros. Passing the var point to console shows that the extension as: `extent_: (4) [Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]`, I guess that is the problem.
Using the `randomLocation.concat(randomLocation);` as a point works in your function, but the zoom is still wrong related to the raster, being now too far away and positioned northwest.

Comment: Point syntax should be `new Point(randomLocation)` without the `{ }`

Comment: Thank you for the correction. This fixed the blank screen problem, but the zoom keeps with the same situation, too far and northwest related to the location.

Comment: You should be seeing something similar to the top screenshot, but with Lages instead of Lausanne, as it's using the same code as "Zoom to Lausanne".  Are you expecting it to be like the second screenshot which is "Zoom to Lausanne" followed by "Center on Lausanne"?

Comment: That is exactly what is happening. I would like something similar to the "Zoom to Switzerland (best fit)", where the zoom fit the extent of the vector, but in my case is a raster. But I can use the location extention for the same purpose.